# How to reset Keras metrics?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

To do some parameter tuning, I like to loop over some training function with Keras. However, I realized that when using `tensorflow.keras.metrics.AUC()` as a metric, for every training loop, an integer gets added to the auc metric name (e.g. auc_1, auc_2, ...). So actually the keras metrics are somehow stored even when coming out of the training function.

This first of all leads to the callbacks not recognizing the metric anymore and also makes me wonder if there are not other things stored like the model weights.

How can I reset the metrics and are there other things that get stored by keras that I need to reset to get a clean restart for training?

Below you can find a minimal working example:

edit: this example seems to only work with tensorflow 2.2

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import AUC


def dummy_network(input_shape):
    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10,
                                 input_shape=input_shape,
                                 activation=tf.nn.relu,
                                 kernel_initializer='he_normal',
                                 kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(l=1e-3)))

    model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(11, activation='sigmoid'))

    model.compile(optimizer='adagrad',
                  loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  metrics=[AUC()])
    return model


def train():
    CB_lr = tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(
        monitor="val_auc",
        patience=3,
        verbose=1,
        mode="max",
        min_delta=0.0001,
        min_lr=1e-6)

    CB_es = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
        monitor="val_auc",
        min_delta=0.00001,
        verbose=1,
        patience=10,
        mode="max",
        restore_best_weights=True)
    callbacks = [CB_lr, CB_es]
    y = [np.ones((11, 1)) for _ in range(1000)]
    x = [np.ones((37, 12, 1)) for _ in range(1000)]
    dummy_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y)).batch(batch_size=100).repeat()
    val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y)).batch(batch_size=100).repeat()
    model = dummy_network(input_shape=((37, 12, 1)))
    model.fit(dummy_dataset, validation_data=val_dataset, epochs=2,
              steps_per_epoch=len(x) // 100,
              validation_steps=len(x) // 100, callbacks=callbacks)


for i in range(3):
    print(f'\n\n **** Loop {i} **** \n\n')
    train()
```

The output is:

```
 **** Loop 0 **** 


2020-06-16 14:37:46.621264: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7f991e541f10 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-06-16 14:37:46.621296: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
Epoch 1/2
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 44ms/step - loss: 0.1295 - auc: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.0310 - val_auc: 0.0000e+00 - lr: 0.0010
Epoch 2/2
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 10ms/step - loss: 0.0262 - auc: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.0223 - val_auc: 0.0000e+00 - lr: 0.0010


 **** Loop 1 **** 


Epoch 1/2
10/10 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4751 - auc_1: 0.0000e+00WARNING:tensorflow:Reduce LR on plateau conditioned on metric `val_auc` which is not available. Available metrics are: loss,auc_1,val_loss,val_auc_1,lr
WARNING:tensorflow:Early stopping conditioned on metric `val_auc` which is not available. Available metrics are: loss,auc_1,val_loss,val_auc_1,lr
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 36ms/step - loss: 0.4751 - auc_1: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.3137 - val_auc_1: 0.0000e+00 - lr: 0.0010
Epoch 2/2
10/10 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2617 - auc_1: 0.0000e+00WARNING:tensorflow:Reduce LR on plateau conditioned on metric `val_auc` which is not available. Available metrics are: loss,auc_1,val_loss,val_auc_1,lr
WARNING:tensorflow:Early stopping conditioned on metric `val_auc` which is not available. Available metrics are: loss,auc_1,val_loss,val_auc_1,lr
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 10ms/step - loss: 0.2617 - auc_1: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.2137 - val_auc_1: 0.0000e+00 - lr: 0.0010


 **** Loop 2 **** 


Epoch 1/2
10/10 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.1948 - auc_2: 0.0000e+00WARNING:tensorflow:Reduce LR on plateau conditioned on metric `val_auc` which is not available. Available metrics are: loss,auc_2,val_loss,val_auc_2,lr
WARNING:tensorflow:Early stopping conditioned on metric `val_auc` which is not available. Available metrics are: loss,auc_2,val_loss,val_auc_2,lr
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 34ms/step - loss: 0.1948 - auc_2: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.0517 - val_auc_2: 0.0000e+00 - lr: 0.0010
Epoch 2/2
10/10 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0445 - auc_2: 0.0000e+00WARNING:tensorflow:Reduce LR on plateau conditioned on metric `val_auc` which is not available. Available metrics are: loss,auc_2,val_loss,val_auc_2,lr
WARNING:tensorflow:Early stopping conditioned on metric `val_auc` which is not available. Available metrics are: loss,auc_2,val_loss,val_auc_2,lr
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 10ms/step - loss: 0.0445 - auc_2: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.0389 - val_auc_2: 0.0000e+00 - lr: 0.0010
```

Comment: I noticed this happens to me even if I create an entirely new model and start over.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your reproducible example failed in several places for me, so I changed just a few things (I'm using TF 2.1). After getting it to run, I was able to get rid of the additional metric names by specifying `metrics=[AUC(name='auc')]`. Here's the full (fixed) reproducible example:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import AUC


def dummy_network(input_shape):
    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10,
                                 input_shape=input_shape,
                                 activation=tf.nn.relu,
                                 kernel_initializer='he_normal',
                                 kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(l=1e-3)))

    model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(11, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(optimizer='adagrad',
                  loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  metrics=[AUC(name='auc')])
    return model


def train():
    CB_lr = tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(
        monitor="val_auc",
        patience=3,
        verbose=1,
        mode="max",
        min_delta=0.0001,
        min_lr=1e-6)

    CB_es = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
        monitor="val_auc",
        min_delta=0.00001,
        verbose=1,
        patience=10,
        mode="max",
        restore_best_weights=True)
    callbacks = [CB_lr, CB_es]
    y = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical([np.random.randint(0, 11) for _ in range(1000)])
    x = [np.ones((37, 12, 1)) for _ in range(1000)]
    dummy_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y)).batch(batch_size=100).repeat()
    val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y)).batch(batch_size=100).repeat()
    model = dummy_network(input_shape=((37, 12, 1)))
    model.fit(dummy_dataset, validation_data=val_dataset, epochs=2,
              steps_per_epoch=len(x) // 100,
              validation_steps=len(x) // 100, callbacks=callbacks)


for i in range(3):
    print(f'\n\n **** Loop {i} **** \n\n')
    train()
```

```
Train for 10 steps, validate for 10 steps
Epoch 1/2
 1/10 [==>...........................] - ETA: 6s - loss: 0.3426 - auc: 0.4530
 7/10 [====================>.........] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3318 - auc: 0.4895
10/10 [==============================] - 1s 117ms/step - loss: 0.3301 - 
                                         auc: 0.4893 - val_loss: 0.3222 - val_auc: 0.5085
```

This happens because every loop, you created a new metric without a specified name by doing this: `metrics=[AUC()]`. The first iteration of the loop, TF automatically created a variable in the name space called `auc`, but at the second iteration of your loop, the name `'auc'` was already taken, so TF named it `auc_1` since you didn't specify a name. But, your callback was set to be based on `auc`, which is a metric that this model didn't have (it was the metric of the model from the previous loop). So, you either do `name='auc'` and overwrite the previous metric name, or define it outside of the loop, like this:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import AUC

auc = AUC()

def dummy_network(input_shape):
    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10,
                                 input_shape=input_shape,
                                 activation=tf.nn.relu,
                                 kernel_initializer='he_normal',
                                 kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(l=1e-3)))

    model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(11, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(optimizer='adagrad',
                  loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  metrics=[auc])
    return model
```

And don't worry about `keras` resetting the metrics. It takes care of all that in the `fit()` method. If you want more flexibility and/or do it yourself, I suggest using custom training loops, and reset it yourself:

```
auc = tf.keras.metrics.AUC()

auc.update_state(np.random.randint(0, 2, 10), np.random.randint(0, 2, 10)) 

print(auc.result())

auc.reset_states()

print(auc.result())
```

```
Out[6]: <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.875>  # state updated
```

```
Out[8]: <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.0>  # state reset
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! weird that the exymple isn't working, I am able to run on 3 different systems with tensorflow 2.2., sorry for that!
Setting the name seems a bit like a brute force answer to me, I'm not sure if it actually solves the problem. How can I know that all the metrics are reset after exiting the "train" function?